# Databinding - error: cannot find symbol variable

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-studio-3.5

I renamed `baseline_check_circle_black_18dp` drawable to `status_paid`. However, I'm getting this:

```
error: cannot find symbol variable baseline_check_circle_black_18dp
```

Have update Android Studio to 3.5.3. Also tried Invalidating cache/Restart. However, unable to resolve the issue.

The new drawable name is not being updated in the binding classes (which are aut-generated by data-binding library). How to regenerate Binding classes?

Answer (score 0):

An xml file had the old name `baseline_check_circle_black_18dp` in it. That was causing the problem. On changing that to `status_paid`, it solved the issue.